# PHPOffice/PHPWord heading tag not display in Correct font sizes in word document

Tags: php, symfony, ms-word, phpword, phpoffice

I am working in symfony PHPOffice/PHPWord document download application. I get document template from the database which has been created previously. for my sample testing I have used

```
   <h1 style="text-align: left; background-color: #33cccc;">Heading 1</h1><h2 style="text-align: left; color: #00ff00; background-color: #ff00ff;">Heading 2</h2><h3 style="text-align: left;">heading 3</h3><h4 style="text-align: left;">heading 4</h4><h5 style="text-align: left;">heading 5</h5><h6 style="text-align: left;">heading 6</h6>
```

I pass the document content to;

```
public function getDocxBuilder(): PhpWord {
    if (is_null($this->docxBuilder)) {
        $this->docxBuilder = new PhpWord();
    }
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);

    return $this->docxBuilder;
}

Html::addHtml($section, $content, false, false);
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($this->docxBuilder, 'Word2007');
```

All above heading tags display in 14pt sizes in the downloaded document. why Heading tag font sizes not working,

Comment: What do you mean by "symfony PHPOffice/PHPWord document"?

Comment: I have used PHPOffice/PHPWord in my symfony framework project. to indicate symfony I used it.

Comment: Ok could you add the version of this library you use and also I don't see any reference to font size in your code, is it a problem of font size in Office/Word document?